# vbs printing script problems

Tags: script, printing, vbscript

Hi all i got some problems with this vbs script

```
set shApp = CreateObject("shell.application")
currentPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetAbsolutePathName(".") 
set shFolder = shApp.NameSpace( currentPath )
set files = shFolder.Items()
for each files in files

if files.name <> "2" then
    'msgbox("printing "&files.name) 
                            files.InvokeVerbEx ("Print") 

end if
next
```

This is supposed to print all the files within the scripts folder BUT it also prints the script's source code, i dont want to print the vbs script itself only the other files how do i do this ? what am i doing wrong ?? 2 is the file name of the script itself 2.vbs

Also how to close word after printing automatically ?

thanks !

Comment: Why wouldn’t you use StrComp in a case like this?

Comment: use it where? example ?

Comment: Instead of your existing comparison.  What did you try?